# What are the disadvantages of double ended dynamic array data structure?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-arrays

Dynamic array is a well-known data structure: we allocate, for example, an array for 8 elements and use these slots while inserting to the end of the array. When we are out of slots, we allocate an array of size 16 and so on. And we get `O(1)` amortized complexity of inserting to the end. Dynamic arrays are implemented in a lot of languages and their standard libraries.

One of the limitations here is that inserting to the beginning of the array is `O(n)` because there are no free slots at the beginning. But why not to have some free slots both *at the beginning and at the end* of the array? It makes inserting on both ends `O(1)` and if we run out of free slots on either side we allocate a bigger array as usual.

It will be less memory efficient than one ended dynamic array (because we need to maintain free slots on both sides), but it's not a bad tradeoff for having `O(1)` inserts on both sides. Or is it? Are there any other disadvantages? I haven't seen this data structure implemented anywhere, what is its fatal flaw?

Comment: I guess it depends on the algorithm, if your algorithm requires you to perform both append and prepend operations then this data structure may give you some benefit. Even in those case a linked list that tracks last element may be more simple to use.

Comment: @Ankur Linked list would be simpler, but here I also have `O(1)` random index access.

Comment: I guess most algorithms just don't need insertion at the begining that often. Grep some Python code base, and count the number of `append` vs the number of `insert(0,`. So most people just don't bother creating that.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my personal take. Like you said, dynamic arrays are pretty straightforward and commonplace, but they definitely don't perform greatly with insertions at the beginning. Something like what you suggest, increasing the size of the array on both ends, is a possibility, and maybe it works fine in some cases, but the algorithm is not as clear as it may look. When growing the internal array, do you always add slack on both ends or only on the side that has been exhausted? Or do you try to keep both margins balanced? This may affect greatly the space efficiency of the structure, in a way that is probably not easy to predict.

On the other hand, if you are going to need insertions at both ends, you can probably use a dynamic circular array. Many implementations of circular arrays have a fixed maximum size, but there is nothing really stopping you from making it dynamic. You can even implement it on top of some dynamic array implementation. Circular arrays introduce a small overhead of adding the base index (which you would need anyway with double-ended slack) and computing the modulo, but they have a predictable and space-efficient behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Actually Some languages have implemented this kind of data-structure, e.g. [deque](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) in C++ STL.

> The complexity (efficiency) of common operations on deques is as
>   follows:
>
> - Random access - constant O(1)
> - Insertion or removal of elements at the end or beginning - constant O(1)
> - Insertion or removal of other elements - linear O(n)

Comment: `std::deque` has the same properties, but it has a more complex implementation. It's a vector of vectors, not one array.